# Trying to understand how `${c}` in this string interpolation points to the elements in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, arrow-functions, string-interpolation

```
const continents = ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Australia', 'Europe'];

const helloContinents = Array.from(continents, c => `Hello ${c}!`);

const message = helloContinents.join(' ');

const element = React.createElement("div", {

  title: "Outer div"

}, React.createElement("h1", null, message));

ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('contents'));
```

Comment: This seems more of a question about how `Array.from` works. Have you read the docs for that function?

Comment: This is same as [].map() used to iterate each elements one by one to do your defined tasks with each elements of array.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs for `Array.from`

> **Parameters**
>
> ***arrayLike*** An array-like or iterable object to convert to an array.
>
> ***mapFn*** Optional Map function to call on every element of the array.
>
> ***thisArg*** Optional Value to use as this when executing mapFn.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Syntax

It says that the second argument is a mapping function, it applies to every element in the array.

Answer (score 0):

> how `${c}` in this string interpolation points to the elements in an array

It does not. `` c => `Hello ${c}!` `` is an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), getting one argument (`c`) at a time.
If you wanted to support environments without string interpolation, you would write
`c => "Hello "+c+"!"`, which can be bloated to `c => {return "Hello "+c+"!";}` in order to emphasize that it is a very compact, but actual function.
10 years ago, without interpolation and arrow functions, you would have written
`function(c){return "Hello "+c+"!";}` there.

So, as other answers/comments point out, using `Array.from(someIterable,someFunction)` simply calls `someFunction` on all elements of `someIterable`, collecting the results in an array. Then `join()` joins array elements into a single string. As your "iterable" is an array already, you could use `Array.map(someFunction)` instead.

Some variations, also added logging where providing the long `function(x)`:

```js
const continents = ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Australia', 'Europe'];
const hellos1 = Array.from(continents,function(x){
  console.log("processing element: "+x);
  return "Hello "+x+"!";
});
console.log(hellos1.join(" "));

const hellos2 = continents.map(x => {return "Hello "+x+"!"});
console.log(hellos2.join()); // comma-separated

console.log(`1+2: ${1+2}, continents.length: ${continents.length}`);
```

The last line shows that the `${...}` thing in string-interpolation simply evaluates the expression inside. So the `c` of `${c}` in the question is not a format specifier, like `\c` could be in various languages, it is `c` simply because that is name of the argument what the arrow function gets.

Answer (score 0):

Just remember to use the back ticks (`) as opposite to single quotes (') in the original syntax of the `mapFn` around the `${c}`:

```
const helloContinents = Array.from(continents, c => `Hello ${c}!`);
```

That is when the content inside the back ticks are evaluated as a function.

Comment: It seems like OP already knows how string interpolation works, but is unclear on how `Array.from` applies the provided function to each individual element.